# Route querystring URL to controller and action in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I'm trying to route an old URL like

`...file.php?a=login`

to a CakePHP request like

`/somecontrollerA/login/`

but it seems that routing only supports the URL without parameters, and `mod_rewrite` does not work since CakePHP uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and not `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.

Is it possible do something like this?

Comment: couse i will need make a 301 for each action, login, logout, register, etc.

Comment: then why don't you route `/file.php` to one action - and handle it there?

Comment: its a possibility. i was looking for use this only to handle invalid requests, example at mod_rewrite

RewriteRule file\.php?a=((login)|(register)|(logout))$ /controller/$1 [L]

then use cakephp routing to redirect file.php (now a invalid request, since continue with old address) to /error/invalidrequest

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found a solution, not really good but worked for the purpose.

open /webroot/index.php

put the following code at start of file (thanks to AD7six)

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace("/^(.*?)\/webroot/", "$1", $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);
}
```

then .htaccess file inside /webroot/ (lines 3 and 4)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^a=login$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)myfile\.php$ controllerA/login [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

now cake recognizes myproject/myfile.php?a=login as /controllerA/login

Comment: For your chosen solution it would be much less intrusive to put in weboot/index.php (an _application_ file) `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.